# ¿Como puedo hacer un git pull en una subrama para que baje los cambios de la rama principal?

Tags: git

Tengo mi rama develop y ahi cree subramas de develop para poder trabajar, subo los commits a cada rama y hago un merge, pero no se como puedo hacer un git pull y actualizar mi subrama a los últimos cambios que hay en develop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda esto.

-Crear una rama a partir de  develop `git checkout -b mod_mi_otra_rama`, estas en la rama develop y creaste esta rama, cuando la creas automaticamente te pasas a la nueva rama

-Actualizar tu rama local con tu repositorio en la nube `git push origin mod_mi_otra_rama` , estas en tu nueva rama y la subiste , creaste la rama en tu repo sincronizado.

> Todo esto es después que la tengas ya sea en [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) o en [Github](https://github.com/), o donde tengas tu código.

-Actualizar tu rama local  `git pull origin mod_mi_otra_rama`, estas parado en la misma rama , y vas actualizar con los cambios que alguien más subió.

-Mezclar tu rama con los últimos cambios locales de develop `git merge develop` , estas en tu rama `mod_mi_otra_rama` y la actualizas con develop

-Actualizar tu rama con los cambios globales de develop  `git pull origin develop`

[Aquí puedes los primeros pasos con GIT](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html)

Espero te sirva. Saludos